# PropertiesMustMatch and ValidatePasswordLength not working

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an MVC4 application and I'm using PropertiesMustMatch and ValidatePasswordLength for password validation.

The strange thing is I keep getting and error saying they don't exist, "Cannot resolve PropertiesMustMatch"

This is my code. Any ideas??

```
 [PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword",
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordsMustMatch",
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
        [ValidatePasswordLength(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: THe PropertiesMustMatch and the ValidatePasswordLength are not standard attributes... have you referenced them correctly in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, but PropertiesMustMatch is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using old techniques?!

instead of PropertiesMustMatch use Compare attribute on ConfirmPassword property, and StringLength or RegularExpression attributes will help you with password length checks

by the way,  take a look at these articles if you must use those attributes

[Blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/07/27/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-validatepasswordlengthattribute.aspx)

you have to add the (old version) reference to your project

Comment: I hope my answer be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have reference for System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Then (if you already have it and it still is not working), create a new MVC project and look them up in data annotations it has.
I am pretty sure they are there.